# custom fonts are not displaying in the site

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I have custom fonts which I would like to import via css using webpack.

css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SBonusDisplay';
    src: url('../../assets/fonts/SBonusDisplay-Regular.ttf')
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'SBonusDisplay' !important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```

This is part of my webpack config:

```
{
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|otf|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name]-[hash:base58:3].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

For some reason the right font is not showing up. its completely different font. any idea what I am doing wrong?

Just u are aware I am working on a PWA Studio Magento web app, the webpack config is quite long and thats why I just paster part of it that is relevant to the loading fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to please give the URL of this site? and please create a proper fontkit with https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

hope you will get the results you want

Comment: do you find it helpful?